# My ASP.NET 4 login stopped working...why?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, aspnetdb

I am working on an ASP.NET 4.0 C# project. The `CreateUserWizard` is working fine, but the login controls I built are always showing this message:

```
Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.
```

This started happening after I changed the membership and connection string settings in machine.config to experiment, which I changed to default later i.e.:

Here's the connection string settings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And here is the membership section:

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
</providers>
</membership>
```

Also, I have changed my default database to store my websites data to login controls default data i.e. `ASPNEDB.mdf` by writing two lines in every code behind of page

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Even when I finish `CreateUserWizard1` successfully and redirect to my homepage.aspx, where I have used default label of asp.net `LoginName`, the label is showing blank.

And if I manually put `Label1` and type `Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;`, its still not working.

Will you please help me. I have to show this project to my college and not only that but my team will fail due to my `EXPERIMENT`.

Comment: If I understand the problem, you are mainly trying to roll back to when it ***was*** working.  I assume you are not using Source Control, correct?

Comment: @jadamel27: Accepted 9 of 14 questions, which isn't that bad. OP could have outstanding questons that are still pending answers.

Comment: @jadamel27 Sorry Sir, AActually I am not satisfied with answers where I had not accepted

Comment: I didn't get it about "If I understand the problem, you are mainly trying to roll back to when it was working. I assume you are not using Source Control," you saying. What is Source Control?

Comment: @Nikhil: I mean something like [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).

Comment: @jadamel27 No Sir, I am not getting it. My Que is why HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; is not recognised or login is getting failed

Comment: If you were using VCS, version control software, you would easily be able to identity what you changed and then undo that. But being with out it makes this a moot point. Since you're using all the default stuff, why not start a new blank solution and build it up to working with the login. Then copy in all your real project code to that.

Comment: I got it now. But still can I know error about why HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; is not recognised or login is getting failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several potential issues here:

1. You changed the machinekey in the web.config.  If so, change it back.  If you can't change it back then delete all the users in your table and recreate them.  You're using a one way hash algorithm that requires the machinekey to hash the entered password for comparison.
2. You made changes to the connection string.  Are you sure the database even has those user records in it?  Next, did you happen to delete / recreate the database?  If so those users are gone.  See #1.

More to the point it's obvious you haven't put everything back like it was.

So, why are you getting login failed? Potential options are:

1. The database being accessed isn't the one you think it is.
2. The user truly doesn't exist in the database its looking at.
3. The user does exist but the password you are providing isn't the correct one.
4. The user exists and the password is correct, but the machinekey has changed and therefore the system can't hash it correctly.

Basically it's probably time to start over by clearing out your database and adding users into it again.

Comment: +1 for check the connection string, in my case I was using the wrong database name between environments :/